# How are the algorithms for JCE providers defined?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, jce, jasypt

I am trying to encrypt a simple string using password based aes encryption using jasypt and I come across in lot of code samples that the algorithm is given as string like "PBEWithSHA512AndAES256-CBC-BC". I am not able to find the document that is relevant to how to understand this string. I understand the parts PBEWithSHA512AndAES256-CBC, but What does the flags BC mean here?

The best resource I could find so far about this is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyManagerFactory

But still it does not answer my question. I have already googled for 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I Found the answer by inspecting the code of bouncy castle

```
   /**
     * PBEWithSHA256And128BitAES-BC
     */
    static public class PBEWithSHA256And128BitAESBC
        extends PBESecretKeyFactory
    {
        public PBEWithSHA256And128BitAESBC()
        {
            super("PBEWithSHA256And128BitAES-CBC-BC", null, true, PKCS12, SHA256, 128, 128);
        }
    }
```

and the definition of the parent class is

```
   public More ...PBESecretKeyFactory(
23        String algorithm,
24        ASN1ObjectIdentifier oid,
25        boolean forCipher,
26        int scheme,
27        int digest,
28        int keySize,
29        int ivSize)
```

so, it has the scheme PKCS12, digest SHA256, 128 bit keysize and 128 bit size for initialization vector